# Mount volume not working in docker

Tags: maven, docker, docker-compose, mount

I am new to docker.I am using **Windows 10** and installed docker for my machine and working docker via power-shell.

My problem was i can't copy my files from docker-compose.yml file

My file look like below

```
version: '2'
services:    
  maven:
   image: maven:3.3.3-jdk-8
   volumes:
    - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    - /d/projects/test/:/code
working_dir: /code
links:
    - mongodb
entrypoint: /code/wait-for-it.sh mongodb:27017 -- mvn clean install
environment: 
        - mongodb_hosts=mongodb
mongodb:
  image: mongo:3.2.4
zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
ports:
  - "2181:2181"
kafka:
  build: .
  ports:
  - "9092"
```

This test project i'm using maven and i have lot of files on it. But it's give the error, like

---

> ERROR: for maven  Cannot start service maven: oci runtime error: exec:
>   "/code/wait-for-it.sh": stat /code/wait-for-it.sh: no such file or
>   directory ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

---

I shared my local drive also in docker settings, still mount problem was there.

Please help me, thanks for advance.